# touchesMoved handle first touch event iOS

Tags: ios, touchesmoved

I'm using this method to move my objects in view:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

In this method I wrote next:

```
NSLog(@"event: %@", event);
```

and get this result:

```
event: <UITouchesEvent: 0x310d00> timestamp: 5277.16 touches: {(
    <UITouch: 0x3f1110> phase: Moved tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x3117d0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x30cb20>> view: <UIView: 0x330520; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x330550>> location in window: {279, 677} previous location in window: {305, 694} location in view: {347, 279} previous location in view: {330, 305},
    <UITouch: 0x4a1a710> phase: Stationary tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x3117d0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x30cb20>> view: (null) location in window: {412, 89} previous location in window: {413, 89} location in view: {412, 89} previous location in view: {413, 89}
)}
```

In this log I can see all my touches (for now this is two touches).

My questions is how to get for touch?

This needs to move my objects.

Now I'm using this:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

But when I move my object I get all values of touches. How to handle just first touch?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you do it, but if you'd really like to know, how to get the very first object, here it goes.

Parameter touches is of `NSSet` type. If you take a look at [NSSet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can also find a method  [`- (NSArray *)allObjects`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000143-CHDDFHBE).

So you could retrieve first touch by:

```
UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Also take a look at [UIEvent Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There you'll find that allTouches is not the only method. Class also knows how to return:

```
- (NSSet *)touchesForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture

- (NSSet *)touchesForView:(UIView *)view

- (NSSet *)touchesForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

All of this methods return a `NSSet`. Which you can *convert* to `NSArray` using `NSSet`'s `allObjects` method.

Comment: You're welcome. But if you'll be using this keep in mind that first object could possibly not be the one you're looking for. Usually your original code is used.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the touch events for dragging the views, you can use an UIPanGestureRecognizer.

The recognizer has properties like minimum /maximum number of touches and made by Apple exactly for dragging the views.

[UIPanGestureRecognizer Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer)